# Confusion in Hartshorne exercise IV.1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

Hartshorne's book Algebraic Geometry, Chapter IV Exercise 1.8 confuses me a bit. It first assumes $X$ is an integral projective scheme of dimension 1 over a field (I assume algebraically closed) $k$. Then in part (b) of the Exercise it says that if the arithmetic genus of $X$ is $0$ then $X$ must be nonsingular. But the cubic curve $y^2-x^3=0$ on the plane is singular and has genus $0$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, the cubic curve $y^2-x^3=0$ is not projective. More importantly, the (naive) projectivization $V(y^2z-x^3)$ has arithmetic genus $1$ via the degree-genus formula. (Fear not - the exercise is correct as written.)

Comment: oh I see. All the while I was believing that arithmetic genus and geometric genus are equal for any curve. So this is only true for smooth curves. Thanks for clarifying.